# How can I get the default web with vbscript on IIS/Windows 7?

Tags: iis, windows-7, vbscript

The following vbscript worked fine on XP computers but is not working on Windows 7 computers.

```
Set objIISRoot = getObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root")

mstrIISRootPath = objIISRoot.Path

' yadda yadda yadda...more stuff goes on..

Set objIISRoot = nothing
```

"objIISRoot" is null so referencing `objIISRoot.Path` throws an error. How do you get at the default web in IIS on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows7 removed the WMI-based administrative programming interface that allows you to do `getObject("iis://localhost...")`

you have a couple options:

- If you are building for IIS7, it may be easier to invoke Appcmd.exe from within script, and then parse the output.  I found that command-line tool to be more intuitive and very powerful. This is an example of doing it from within Javascript:

```
    
    function RunAppCmd(command, deleteOutput) {
        deleteOutput = deleteOutput || false;
        LogMessage("RunAppCmd("+command+") ENTER");
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpdir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.TemporaryFolder);
        var tmpFileName = fso.BuildPath(tmpdir, fso.GetTempName());
        var windir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.WindowsFolder);
        var appcmd = fso.BuildPath(windir,"system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe") + " " + command;

        LogMessage("shell.Run("+appcmd+")");

        // use cmd.exe to redirect the output
        var rc = shell.Run("%comspec% /c " + appcmd + "> " + tmpFileName, WindowStyle.Hidden, true);
        LogMessage("shell.Run rc = "  + rc);

        if (deleteOutput) {
            fso.DeleteFile(tmpFileName);
        }
        return {
            rc : rc,
            outputfile : (deleteOutput) ? null : tmpFileName
        };
    }
```

I guess the VBScript would be pretty similar.

- On the other hand if you are building this  thing for both XP and Win7, then you will need to stay with the COM monikers.  To allow this on Win7 you need to install the IIS6 Management pack. Access it via `Start...Run...optionalfeatures.exe` and then turn on the WMI stuff.

[image]

After doing that your old WMI script will run.

Comment: Great answer. I also had to enable IIS 6 Scripting Tools. The last one (IIS Metabase) enabled itself automatically.